# How to overload a method to accept a Linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

### The Setup

I've got a method called WhereIn() that accepts a params object[] values:

```
public bool WhereIn(params object[] values)
```

### The Problem

Unfortunately is it's really easy to make the mistake of calling `WhereIn(values.Select(v => v.Id))`.

This results a Linq expression being passed in, rather that the values getting enumerated to an array. How do I overload my method to accept the linq expression?

### My Best Guess

My current best guess is to make an IEnumerable overload, and then have to check for it being a string, and then stuffing the string into an object array to call the other overload:

```
public bool WhereIn<T>(IEnumerable<T> values){
    if(values.GetType().Name == "String"){
        return WhereIn(new object[]{values});
    } else {
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

I'm not really happy about having to manually check for a string type, and I'm afraid I might miss some other class that implements IEnumerable, that should be wrapped in an object array .

Comment: What are the semantics of `WhereIn`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2128841/284240

Comment: @Jon It creates a Microsoft CRM QueryExpression, that gets used to generate a SQL statement on the server side.  So I use it like this: crmdataContext.GetAllEntitiesWhereIn<Contact>("contactid", guid1, guid2, guid3);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following two signatures:

```
public bool WhereIn<T>(params T[] values);
public bool WhereIn<T>(IEnumerable<T> values);
```

... and you call it like this:

```
WhereIn("hi")
```

This will call the first method, passing it a single-element `string[]`.

Comment: That actually might work.  I was just figured there would be a way to specify a method that accepts linq expression like list.select(i => i.Id);

Comment: @Daryl: `list.select(i => i.Id)` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, so this will work for that.

Comment: @Daryl are you saying you want your method to take an `IEnumerable<T>` and a linq expression?

Comment: @Craig Basically if you attempt to pass in list.select(i => i.id), it'll compile just fine, but bomb when it runs.  So I need to enumerate the result to an array (call ToArray) then call the params object[] overload.  I could do some weird type checks if the length of the params array is 1, but the developer would have no idea what I'm doing and why list.select(i => i.ID) magically works.

Comment: @Daryl: Why would it "bomb when it runs?" I have tested this, and it works just fine if you pass in `list.Select(i => i.Id)`.

Comment: @Daryl I think I was confused when you said "a method that accepts linq expression"...did you mean a method that accepts `IEnumerable<T>`? If so then I think this answer is what you're after. I thought you had meant a predicate.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior It isn't this initial method that is bombing, it's the method that this method is calling.  With your solution, I'm able to convert the IEnumerable to an object[], which then works fine.  Without your solution, the base method WhereIn(params object[] values) calls will treat my ienumerable collection as a single object.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the `System.Collections.Generic.Contains()` method and save yourself un-needed headaches trying to "reinvent the wheel".

Comment: Except that I'm actually passing these parameters to a another method that I don't own that's part of Microsoft CRM, that then is used to build a QueryExpression and go query the database.  Contains no work. :)

Comment: A realistic example of what you want to achieve would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What if you did something like this...
**Edit:** I include a test method so you can try different select(a => a.Id) if you want

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var test = new[] {
        new { Id = 1, Name = "John" },
        new { Id = 2, Name = "George" },
    };

    if (WhereIn(test.Select(a => a.Name)))
    {

    }


}

//Works with value types, strings, and classes
public bool WhereIn<T>(IEnumerable<T> values)
{
    var objectArray = new object[values.Count()];

    for (int index = 0; index < values.Count(); index++)
    {
        objectArray[index] = values.ElementAt(index);
    }

    return WhereIn(objectArray);
}

// This was just for test purposes
public bool WhereIn(params object[] values)
{

     return true;
}
```

I have run this in Visual studio Test and seems to work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Except that a string object would fail miserably and value type arrays are not covariant.

Comment: I see... I have made adjustments. Working for me.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried it but could you not do

```
WhereIn(values.Select(v => v.Id).ToArray<Type_of_Value>())
```

where Type_of_Value is the type used in your values collection

Comment: idk, I didn't down vote you.  the ToArray is ideally what I need to be calling, the only problem is you don't get a compiler error if you forget, but it will cause the program to error.  So I'm trying to make more of a Pit of Success (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/10/02/50420.aspx)